# How to filter the array and then use map method to output it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter

I'm trying to use:

1..cards**.filter** method to find cards number === TRUE, 2..then use cards**.map** method to **innerHTML** cards.symbol value without the number value.

The end result should be 9 divs displayd in my index.html file ->
`<div class="cards">1</div>`
`<div class="cards">2</div>`
`<div class="cards">3</div>`
`<div class="cards">4</div>`
`<div class="cards">5</div>`
`<div class="cards">6</div>`
`<div class="cards">7</div>`
`<div class="cards">8</div>`
`<div class="cards">9</div>`

//HTML

```
 <body>
    <h1>Filter Method</h1>
    <div class="container" id="filter-method"></div>
</body>
```

//JAVASCRIPT

```
const cards = [
    {  symbol: '1', number: true},
    {  symbol: '2', number: true},
    {  symbol: '3', number: true},
    {  symbol: '4', number: true},
    {  symbol: '5', number: true},
    {  symbol: '6', number: true},
    {  symbol: '7', number: true},
    {  symbol: '8', number: true},
    {  symbol: '9', number: true},
    {  symbol: '+', number: false},   
    {  symbol: '-', number: false},   
    {  symbol: '*', number: false} 
    ];
    
    const cardsContainer = document.querySelector('#filter-method');
    
    const filteredCards = cards.filter((card) => {
      if(card.number === true){
        return '<div class="card">' + '<span>' + card.symbol  + '<span>' + '</div>';
      }
})

cardsContainer.innerHTML = filteredCards.join('\n');
```

Comment: try this `cards.filter(v=>v.number).map(v=>`<div class="card"><span>${v.symbol}</span></div>`).join('\n');;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` should return true or false to determine whether to include that item and then `map` can be used to turn it to html. I've assumed you want to keep the `<span>` elements too.

```js
const cards = [
    {  symbol: '1', number: true},
    {  symbol: '2', number: true},
    {  symbol: '3', number: true},
    {  symbol: '4', number: true},
    {  symbol: '5', number: true},
    {  symbol: '6', number: true},
    {  symbol: '7', number: true},
    {  symbol: '8', number: true},
    {  symbol: '9', number: true},
    {  symbol: '+', number: false},   
    {  symbol: '-', number: false},   
    {  symbol: '*', number: false} 
    ];
    
const cardsContainer = document.querySelector('#filter-method');
    
const filteredCards = cards.filter(card => card.number).map(card => {
    return '<div class="card">' + '<span>' + card.symbol  + '</span>' + '</div>';
})
    
cardsContainer.innerHTML = filteredCards.join("\n")
```

```html
<div class="container" id="filter-method"></div>
```

Comment: Lovely, Thank you for your time Jamiec.
That's exaclty what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: Jamiec, I'm having hard time to understant this function with multiple methos.
const filteredCards = cards.filter(card => card.number).map(card => {
Can you please try to explain it to me in the simpliest way possible?

Comment: @PaulC both `filter` and `map` are methods which act on an array, and return an array. So they are just chained one after another. You could do it in multiple steps too - `const filteredCards = cards.filter(....)` and then `const html = filteredCards.map(...)`. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

You could do everything in one go using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const cards = [
  { symbol: '1', number: true },
  { symbol: '2', number: true },
  { symbol: '3', number: true },
  { symbol: '4', number: true },
  { symbol: '5', number: true },
  { symbol: '6', number: true },
  { symbol: '7', number: true },
  { symbol: '8', number: true },
  { symbol: '9', number: true },
  { symbol: '+', number: false },
  { symbol: '-', number: false },
  { symbol: '*', number: false }
];

const cardsContainer = document.querySelector('#filter-method');

cardsContainer.innerHTML = cards.reduce((strHTML, card) => {
  if (card.number) strHTML += `<div class="card"><span>${card.symbol}</span></div>`
  return strHTML;
}, '')
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Filter Method</h1>
  <div class="container" id="filter-method"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Secan thank you for you time and good answer, most definatly gonna use that in the future. But for now  I'm still on learning stages and I was trying to practice and understand  .filter and .map methods..

Comment: Just to give you an idea of how "powerful" the `Array.prototype.reduce()` method is, just consider this: with `.filter()` + `.map()` + `.join()` you have a total of 30 iterations over the `cards` array and its filtered subset (12 for filtering, 9 for mapping, 9 for joining); with `.reduce()` you have only 12 iterations to obtain the same result. That is definitely a tool you want to add to your kit once you are confident with `.map()` and `.filter()` ;)